# Sum values in RDLC with two datasets according to condition

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc, iif-function

I need to sum some values and show in RDLC. RDLC contains two datasets. There are two fields from same dataset; TipValute and Iznos.
IF TipValute contains value 0 then sum all values from field Iznos.

My expression looks like:

```
=Sum(IIF(First(Fields!TipValute.Value=0, "DataSet1"),First(Fields!Iznos.Value, "DataSet1"),0))
```

But I'm getting error like

> Error 3   The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox96’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset.

and

> Error 1   The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox96.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ uses a First, Last or Previous aggregate in an outer aggregate.  These aggregate functions cannot be specified as nested aggregates.

Than I tried with this expression

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!TipValute.Value=0, Fields!Iznos.Value, 0), "DataSet1")
```

But in report i get #Error

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If should be:

```
Sum(IIf(Fields!TipValute.Value=0, cdbl(Fields!Iznos.Value), 0), "DataSet1")
```

Seems that the key was in **cdbl**

Comment: It works well in IIS server but not work on local pc.

Comment: strange because my project is running on local PC and database is mySQL

Comment: my database is oracle

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

=Sum(IIF(Fields!TipValute.Value=0, Fields!Iznos.Value,0))